# How can a screen be recorded on an iOS 9 device?

Tags: ios9, screen-recording

Could you please advise on how to record screen of an iOS 9 device? iRec, Shou do not work. Reflector 2 and X-Mirage also do not work (tried for iPhone 5 / iOS 9.0.2 - Win 10).
Thanks,
Yaroslav

Answer (score 0):

Reflector 2 works after reinstalling. It's a paid solution, but works good